# How can I use Kubernetes Python API to get clusters information?

Tags: python, api, kubernetes

I'm seeking the answer regarding how to use the Kubernetes Python API to get cluster information (`kubectl get clusters`).

```
~$ kubectl -n <namespace> get clusters
NAME         AGE
cluster-1   6d17h
cluster-2   6d17h
```

Comment: That's not a core resource type that I know of, is it a CRD?

Comment: Seems to be related to https://kubernetes.github.io/cluster-registry/userguide.html

Comment: Please check https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Comment: As this is CRD https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python won't help much.

Comment: configuration = client.Configuration()
    api_instance = client.AppsV1beta2Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))
    try:
        api_response = api_instance.list_namespaced_stateful_set(namespace)
        for cluster in api_response.items:
            clusters['name'] = cluster.metadata.labels['operator.io/cluster']
            clusters_info.append(clusters.copy())
        return clusters_info
    except ApiException as e:
        return "Exception when calling AppsV1beta2Api->patch_namespaced_stateful_set_status: %s\n" % e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the cluster name for the configmap used for clusterConfiguration. This config map exists if the cluster is a kubeadm one.

https://github.com/dguyhasnoname/k8s-cluster-checker/blob/master/objects/cluster.py#L17

below snippet fetches configmap from python client using module get-cm.py(in modules folder of above repo). It checks if clusetConfiguration configmap `kubeadm-config` is present and if found, greps out the cluster name. You can put configMap of your cluster in below snippet and try running the script.

```
    def get_cluster_name():
        cm = K8sConfigMap.get_cm('kube-system')
        for item in cm.items:
            if 'kubeadm-config' in item.metadata.name:
                if 'clusterName' in item.data['ClusterConfiguration']:
                    cluster_name = re.search(r"clusterName: ([\s\S]+)controlPlaneEndpoint", \
                    item.data['ClusterConfiguration']).group(1)
                    print ( "\nCluster name: {}".format(cluster_name))
```

the grepping of cluster name is happening in below line:

```
re.search(r"clusterName: ([\s\S]+)controlPlaneEndpoint",
```

cluster name value is found between `clusterName:` and `controlPlaneEndpoint` strings. You can change these strings if needed, according to your env.

Answer (score 1):

This one maybe help you, [at](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/d8f283e7483848647804eab345645106b6fb357d/examples/remote_cluster.py#L24)

```
from pick import pick  # install pick using `pip install pick`

from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client import configuration


def main():
    contexts, active_context = config.list_kube_config_contexts()
    if not contexts:
        print("Cannot find any context in kube-config file.")
        return
    contexts = [context['name'] for context in contexts]
    active_index = contexts.index(active_context['name'])
    cluster1, first_index = pick(contexts, title="Pick the first context",
                                 default_index=active_index)
    cluster2, _ = pick(contexts, title="Pick the second context",
                       default_index=first_index)

    client1 = client.CoreV1Api(
        api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster1))
    client2 = client.CoreV1Api(
        api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster2))

    print("\nList of pods on %s:" % cluster1)
    for i in client1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces().items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
              (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))

    print("\n\nList of pods on %s:" % cluster2)
    for i in client2.list_pod_for_all_namespaces().items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
              (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work with `config.load_incluster_config()`: `kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.`

Answer (score -3):

Below is the code to get the cluster info (CRD):

```
clusters_info = []
d1  = {}
config.load_kube_config()
#config.load_incluster_config()
configuration = client.Configuration()
api_instance = client.AppsV1beta2Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))
try:
   api_response = api_instance.list_namespaced_stateful_set(namespace)
   for cluster in api_response.items:
       d1['name']=cluster.metadata.labels['operator.io/cluster']
       clusters_info.append(d1.copy())
   return clusters_info
except ApiException as e:
   return "Exception when calling AppsV1beta2Api->patch_namespaced_stateful_set_status: %s\n" % e
```

Comment: this code of yours makes no sense. `return cluster-info`? where is cluster-info? You are listing `StatefulSets`.

Comment: api_response = api_instance.list_namespaced_stateful_set(namespace)
   for cluster in api_response.items:
       d1['name']=cluster.metadata.labels['operator.io/cluster']
       clusters_info.append(d1.copy())