# Equivalent of 'kubectl cluster-info' in kubernetes python client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster, kubernetes-python-client

Is there any equivalent kubernetes python client function for

`kubectl cluster-info`

which output

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.x.x.x:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.x.x.x:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Comment: Try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483772/how-can-i-use-kubernetes-python-api-to-get-clusters-information